# android reading user input in a service

Tags: java, android

I want to write an android app that would be a background service that would listen for either a specific gesture or key press in the and then trigger an action.  Is it even possible to do such a thing with a service?  If so could someone guide me the right direction.  I have search high and low can could seem to find an answer.

Comment: In general you should not be able to capture gestures or key presses from a service. Have a look at the google Gesture Search bar. They use a long press on the search button to open up an activity that then captures the gesture. But I don't know what intent or signal they use to get notified of the long search press.

Answer (score 1):

not hard to read where they touch, but the touches in this way provide only location, not time, not on ups or downs.

in your service

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (layout != null) {
        ((WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE)).removeView(layout);
        layout = null;
    }
}
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
    WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
    params.setTitle("test");
    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
    wm.addView(layout, params);
}
```

and for your touch handler, it will have to be as

```
public boolean gestureHandler(MotionEvent event, boolean eat) {
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE)
```

Comment: Window manager will not let you add views from a service...This code raises an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Doing this (except on top of apps that cooperate by sending you their input) would be a huge security hole of the kind that the android architecture is designed to prohibit.  To do it you would need to modify the platform and have the watching done by something running with access to the raw touch and button input, possibly as part of the driver for that.

In other words you can with difficulty do it on your own rooted phone or on devices you manufacture, but it's not usable for most people.