# Accelerometer in background service?

Tags: android

Is it possible to read from accelerometer sensor in android while the application is in background ?
I've read that its not possible to get touch inputs while being on background is that also true ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes you can read the sensors
but you have to implement a service 
http://developerlife.com/tutorials/?p=356

as for the input [android reading user input in a service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3757220/android-reading-user-input-in-a-service)

Answer (score 0):

Since there are apps that mutes your phone when placing it upside down, and other apps that 'launch' when you do a certain gesture on the screen, I think both things you're asking about are doable.

Answer (score 0):

Even an activity can still run in the background, you just have to make sure you do NOT unregister the event listener at onPause().

A Service is not much more than an activity without a UI. So in this case it may be 'better' to create a service but it is certainly not necessary if you feel the overhead of adding a service and the communications involved are not worth it, especially the broadcasting, if you do it too much may cost you in terms of performance and energy consumption.