# Android start app automatically after x time duration if user cannot touch or use the device

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-service, android-broadcast, android-timepicker

I am stuck and working on android app, i want when i close my application,then if user do not touch screen for x time, for example for 1minute user do not touch the screen or use the device then my application start automatically after x time..how i can achieve this please help..Thanks

Comment: can u pls share how u  achieve this task ?

Comment: @Erum the question is one year old,and i forgot the module and today and yesterday i am busy to achieve my deadlines,i will check this module on weekend and will let u know.

Answer (score 4):

You could make use of service. As soon as your application is exited you could start a timer or counter. If there are no interactions on phone by the user you could start your activity from ur service (or) You could implement ur service in such a way that when the phone is going into sleep mode(which means there was no interaction by the user on the phone) you can start your activity.

**UPDATED**

```
    protected CountDownTimer timer = new CountDownTimer(5000, 5000){
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
             Log.d("onTick", "Entered");
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
             Log.d("onFinish", "Entered");
        }
    };
```

Comment: thanks alot for ur reply..through services i have done the when phone is going to sleep then after 3minutes my app start automatically and work's fine..but now my problem is when i close my application,and if user do not interaction or use the phone then my application start automatically after x time duration..can u got my point?

Comment: can u please tell me that how i can start timer if ther is no interaction by the user...if user is intercation then how to reset timer?

Comment: I am not quite sure but u can refer this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11782501/how-to-detect-user-interaction-of-any-kind

Comment: make use of CountDownTimer class to start and stop the timer

Comment: bro can u give example of starting sountdwon timer?please

Comment: I have ediited my ans. To start the timer call timer.start() and to stop timer.stop(). This particular timer is for 5s (5000 ms)